# Outbound message hits webservice continously

Tags: webservices, integration, workflowoutboundmessage, .net

I have a webservice written in .net which gets the request from the outbound message and sends the response. But salesforce keeps hitting my application and it still waits in outbound queue. How do I stop salesforce to hit the application once the response is received? Following is my code sample

```
notificationsResponse INotificationBinding.Pur(PTrans.notifications PurP)
    {
        string id,session = null;
        PTrans.notifications test = PurP;
        session = test.SessionId;
        string url = test.EnterpriseUrl;
        PTrans.Transaction__cNotification[] request = PurP.Notification;
        PTrans.notificationsResponse response = new notificationsResponse();
        response.Ack = true;
        return response;
    }
```

When I tested with soapui, I get the following response,

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <notificationsResponse xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
         <Ack>true</Ack>
      </notificationsResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But it still hits the application continuously. Help me to sort what the problem is

Comment: Some firewall issues maybe? Can you try hitting your service from outside (not from your office's network)?

Comment: Yes, I have tried hitting from outside still the same problem exists @eyescream

Comment: What if you'll try to send the message from SF as HTTP request? It'll be synchronous so at least you'll get either the response SF receives or for example a timeout...

Comment: The queue monitoring page should say why its still in the queue, what does it say for your retried messages?

Comment: I dint get any messages. If it triggers only once then there is no prob. If it  is more than once, I get this prob. I resolved this making field update to false once it is triggered.Workflow will trigger only if that field is set true

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce will keep retransmitting the message until it believes it was acknowledge alright.

Can you confirm the raw response from your service actually looks like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <notificationsResponse xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
            <Ack>true</Ack>
       </notificationsResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: When I checked with soapui, I get the response as you mentioned above. Here is my response                           <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <notificationsResponse xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
         <Ack>true</Ack>
      </notificationsResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: I am not able to sort where the problem is